# Shade and calculate specific area

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, area, curve

I tried to change the code in a way so that only the first area is shaded grey. How can I set the horizontal line in a way that it only appears under the area I want to shade?

Furthermore I want to calculate the area of ONE region. How do I achieve that? I know it is `trapz` but I am not sure how to set the boundaries. Thanks!

```
x = 0:.01:4*pi;  %// x data
y = sin(x);      %// y data
level = 0.5;     %// level
plot(x, y)
hold on
area(x, max(y, level), level, 'EdgeColor', 'none', 'FaceColor', [.7 .7 .7])
```

**Curve:-**
[image: Curve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try also this simple option:

```
x = 0:.01:4*pi;  %// x data
y = sin(x);      %// y data
level = 0.5;     %// level
lineStart = find(y>=level,1);
lineEnd = find(y(lineStart:end)<=level,1)+lineStart;
plot(x,y)
hold all
area(x(lineStart:lineEnd),y(lineStart:lineEnd),...
     level,'EdgeColor', 'none', 'FaceColor', [.7 .7 .7],'ShowBaseLine','off')
line([x(lineStart),x(lineEnd)],[level level ])
hold off
```

without defining areas of interest a-priory:
[image: Filling area]

And don't forget to `hold off`...

To calaulate the area:
`A = trapz(x(lineStart:lineEnd),y(lineStart:lineEnd))`

Comment: Thanks for your efforts mate! One question. What does the 1 mean in `lineStart = find(y>=level,1);`

Comment: It means 'look for the first time the condition is true', so it only gives the first increase of `y` above the the level

Answer (score 2):

You can limit the range of your x axis in the `area` plot to the range of interest, e.g. from 0 to 4 and then calculate the resulting values of the function in this range. For the base line: you can hide it in the `area` command and add it manually using the `line` command.

```
x = 0:.01:4*pi;  %// x data
y = sin(x);      %// y data
level = 0.5;     %// level
plot(x, y)
hold on

x_interest = 0:.01:4;
y_interest = sin(x_interest);
area(x_interest, max(y_interest, level), level, ...
    'EdgeColor', 'none', 'FaceColor', [.7 .7 .7], ...
    'ShowBaseLine', 'off');
line( [ min(x_interest) max(x_interest) ], [ level level ] )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! :) How can I know calculate the area of the given surface. Pretty sure it is trapz but am not sure about the boundaries. If I have no points given explicitly I probably need to use intersection. Any ideas from your side?

Comment: @Detox: you're right. I have missed that part of your question. Hope this helps: https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/15653-evaluating-the-area-between-two-curves

Comment: Thanks! One last question. If I want to shade another area below my shaded in the picture but it is in the lower sector, area will also fill the sector between the two lines. How can I avoid such occurence?

Comment: @Detox: what do you mean? The same threshold, but under the line? I'd use an additional call to `area`, like this: `area(x_interest2, min(y_interest2, level), level, 'EdgeColor', 'none', 'FaceColor', [.7 .7 .7],     'ShowBaseLine', 'off');` -- and use `min` instead of `max`.