# Data evaluation

Tags: matlab, plot, figure

I have some data in MATLAB, and want to distinguish the start and stop point when these data cross specified threshold (for example `-50`), and save them and then calculate the approximate area of that section under `-50` and if it was below some defined value neglect those points and check for the next two points. See the following image:

[image: Figure]

The two points on the left side of the figure are marked with `x` in red and the required area is shown in green. I want to do this for the whole figure.

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: So you want to calculate the area under the curve that is lower than a given threshold ?

Comment: First distinguish those points that are passing -50 and save them, and then calculate the area of each section under -50 separately in the curve.

Comment: Your question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38420623/shade-and-calculate-specific-area) which already has an answer, you should find inspiration there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shade and calculate specific area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38420623/shade-and-calculate-specific-area)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the plotting, there were possible ways mentioned in the comments, whereas I commonly would use [`patch`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch.html) to plot filled polygonal regions. For the area approximation, you can use the [`trapz`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/trapz.html) function for a trapezoidal numerical integration.

That'd be my solution, including detection of the intervals, and also neglecting intervals with insufficient area (it's a bit lengthy, and full of loops for plotting all the intervals; can be certainly optimized):

```matlab
% Set up function, and parameter(s)
x = linspace(-0.125*pi, 4.125*pi, 10001);
y = linspace(60, 100, 10001) .* sin(x);
thr = -50;
thr_area = 30;

% Find y values lower than threshold
y_idx = find(y <= thr);

% Get start and end of intervals
idx_int = find(diff(y_idx) > 1);
n_int = numel(idx_int)+1;
s = zeros(n_int, 1);
e = zeros(n_int, 1);
s(1) = y_idx(1);
e(end) = y_idx(end);
for k = 1:n_int-1
  e(k) = y_idx(idx_int(k));
  s(k+1) = y_idx(idx_int(k)+1);
end

% Calculate areas
Q = zeros(n_int, 1);
for k = 1:n_int
  Q(k) = abs(trapz(x(s(k):e(k)), y(s(k):e(k))-thr));
end

% Visualization
figure(1);
hold on;
plot(x, y);
xlim([x(1), x(end)]);
ylim([min(y)-10, max(y)+10]);
plot([x(1), x(end)], [thr thr], 'k');
for k = 1:n_int
  patch(x(s(k):e(k)), y(s(k):e(k)), 'k');
  plot([x(s(k)), x(e(k))], [y(s(k)), y(e(k))], 'r.', 'MarkerSize', 15);
  text(x(s(k)), thr+20, num2str(Q(k)));
  if (Q(k) < thr_area)
    text(x(s(k)), thr+10, 'Area too low');
  else
    text(x(s(k)), thr+10, 'Area OK');
  end
end
hold off;
```

The result looks like this:

[image: Output]

You should have all information by now to do whatever further calculations, analyses, etc. you have in mind.

Hope that helps!

Disclaimer: I tested the code with Octave 5.1.0, but I'm quite sure, that it should be fully MATLAB-compatible. If not, please leave a comment, and I'll try to fix possible issues.

Comment: Thanks @HansHirse, this code perfectly works but there is small problem with it that it choses y = -53 or y = -52 also. Maybe adding another threshold for this would help!

Comment: @FR I don't understand. All `y` values below the threshold are taken into account, yes. But, to find the proper interval start and ending (`y` crossing the threshold), I take the first and last element of that "section". To calculate the area, I need all `y` values from the interval.

Comment: Yea, I noticed that. It's perfectly coded but in my data it choses those values of y that are -52 and -53 as well. I have to check them in detail :) thanks. @HansHirse

Comment: @FR this is exactly why I've added my answer. Since your data do not contains the exact threshold value, matlab will pick up the closest value after the threshold.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @HansHirse's answer, it could be useful to interpolate your data to find the threshold crossing points.

For example if your data looks like that:

```
x = [ 1  2  3  4];
y = [47 49 51 53];
```

`y` do not contains the exact threshold value (50), so we can interpolate those data to guess where, according to `x`, we will reach `y = 50`.

```
x_interp = [ 1  2 2.5  3  4];
y_interp = [47 49 50  51 53];
```

**Crossing points without interpolation:**

```
% Dummy data
x = 0:0.2:5*pi;
y = sin(x)*10;

% Threshold
T = 5;

% Crossing points
ind = find(abs(diff(sign(y-T)))==2)+1
xind = x(ind)
yind = y(ind)

% Plot
plot(x,y);
hold on
plot(xind,yind,'o','markersize',2,'color','r')
```

[image]

**Crossing points with interpolation:**

```
% Dummy data
x = 0:0.2:5*pi;
y = sin(x)*10;

% Threshold
T = 5;

%% Crossing points interpolation
% Index where intersection occurs
ind = [find(abs(diff(sign(y-T)))==2)+1].'+[-1,0]

% For example we could obtain:
%        [5;              [4, 5;  %We cross the threshold between y(4) and y(5)
% ind =  10;   + [-1,0] =  9,10;  %We cross the threshold between y(9) and y(10)
%        18]              17,18]  %...

xind = x(ind)
yind = y(ind)-T
% Linear interpolation
xint = xind(:,1)-yind(:,1)./(diff(yind,1,2)./diff(xind,1,2))
yint = T

% Plot
plot(x,y);
hold on
plot(xint,yint,'o','markersize',2,'color','r')
```

[image]

Then simply add those new interpolated values to your original vectors:

```
[x,pos] = sort([x xint]);
y       = [y yint];
y       = y(pos);

% Now apply the @HansHirse's solution.
% ...
```

Comment: I did not quiet grasp .'+[-1,0] in your code.

Comment: @FR I've added an example in my code, `.'` is the transpose operator: `[column vector].' = [row vector]`.

Comment: Ok, I see, so this code in general is for picking the closest values to the threshold, right? @obchardon